# Inner product with two different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space. If $B= \{ b_{1}, b_{2},\cdots, b_{n}\}$ is a basis for $V$, show that $B'=\{f_{1},f_{2},\cdots,f_{n}\}$ is also a basis for $V$ with property $\langle f_{i},b_{i}\rangle=1$ and $\langle f_{j},b_{i}\rangle=0$ for all $i\neq j$.
Proof. I am trying to show $B'$ is a basis by showing $B'$ is linearly independent and $V=span(B')$. First, let $k_{1}f_{1}+\cdots+k_{n}f_{n}=0$, then $\langle k_{1}f_{1}+\cdots+k_{n}f_{n},b_{j}\rangle=0$ for $1\leq j\leq n$ or $k_{j}\langle f_{j},b_{j}\rangle=0$, hence $k_{j}=0$ for $1\leq j\leq n$, i.e., $B'$ is linearly independent. Next, let $v\in V$, then $v=\alpha_{1} b_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n} b_{n}$ since $B$ is a basis for $V$. I got $\langle v,f_{1}\rangle=\alpha_{1},\cdots,\langle v,f_{n}\rangle=\alpha_{n}$. so, $v=\langle v,f_{1}\rangle b_{1}+\cdots+\langle v,f_{n}\rangle b_{n}$.

I didn't know how to continue this proof and make $B'$ as a basis for $V$.

Comment: The statement you wrote doesn't make much sense. Please check it...what are the $\;f',$s, to beginwith?

Comment: What can you say about a set of $n$ LI vectors in a space of dimension $n$?

Comment: **A classic**: take $f^i=\sum_sg^{is}b_s$ where $[g^{kl}]$ is the matrix inverse of $[\langle b_k,\ b_l\rangle]$. This last one is invertible because $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @DonAntonio $f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}$ are elements in $V$ such that $\langle f_{i},b_{i}\rangle=1$ and  $\langle f_{i},b_{j}\rangle=0$ for $i\neq j$

Comment: once you have $n$ linearly independent generators for $B'$ verified, the fact that its span is $n$ dimensional $=\dim V$ tells you it spans $V$

Comment: @YSA That is not what your question says. It says "SHOW that B'... is also a basis with property...etc."

Comment: @ancientmathematician, user8675309: Now I remember this properties: “ If $S=\{v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}\}$ is linearly independent in $V$ an $n$-dimensional Vector Space, then $S$ spans $V$ and $S$ is a basis of $V$”. Since $B’=\{ f_{1}, \cdots,f_{n}\}$ in $V$ ($n$-dimensional Vector space) is linearly independent, then $B’$ is a basis for $V$. Thank you everyone for your kindly help.